# Does Snap SPARQL API exist?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, sparql, semantic-web

I am new in Semantic Web Application.

Here I intend to use Snap SPARQL for querying my project because I want to use reasoning. But so far, I just found Snap SPARQL Plugin for Protege. I need a **Snap SPARQL API** that I can use to code in Eclipse.

So, does Snap SPARQL API exist?

I tried to use this dependency on Maven project based on [this link](https://github.com/protegeproject/snap-sparql-query), but it failed.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.protege</groupId>
    <artifactId>snap-sparql-query-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

> Failed to read artifact descriptor for edu.stanford.protege:snap-sparql-query-api:jar:2.0.0

How I should write the dependency? or where I should download .jar file?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a Protege plugin, I don't know why you need this and for what.

Comment: Moreover, you should read a bit more about Maven, there is not only the artifact type `jar` but also others like `pom`, `bundle`, ... And the one you mean doesn't provide a JAR file but a BUNDLE, i.e. `<type>bundle</type>`

Comment: From my point of view, you only need the dependency to the SPARQL-DL API, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Thank you @AKSW for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it exists. You can find it here:

https://github.com/protegeproject/autoupdate/tree/master/snap-sparql-query

According to this page, Snap SPARQL is :

> A [Protégé] plug-in for querying ontologies with SPARQL-DL.  This plug-in was
>   developed for  tutorial purposes as part of the 
>   Protege [Short Course series](http://protege.stanford.edu/short-courses.php).   We make no quality guarantees regarding use in
>   production environments.

Comment: Thank you for the link :)
Yes a Snap-SPARQL is a plugin for Protege, so I am not able to use it with Java coding. Then I tried to use SPARQL-DL to do it.

Comment: You are welcome. If you find it useful, you can click to accept the answer and to upvote it.